# Sorting a dictionary by its sub value

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I currently have a dictionary in Python3 that looks like this

```
{'parentkey1': {'value1': 3, 'value2': 0},
 'parentkey2': {'value1': 2, 'value2': 5},
 'parentkey3': {'value1': 6, 'value2': 9},
 'parentkey4': {'value1': 8, 'value2': 3}
 }
```

Is there a way that I can arrange the nested dictionary that it becomes

```
{'parentkey1': {'value2': 0, 'value1': 3},
 'parentkey2': {'value1': 2, 'value2': 5},
 'parentkey3': {'value1': 6, 'value2': 9},
 'parentkey4': {'value2': 3, 'value1': 8}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since python 3.6 the [dictionaries are insertion ordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6) so you can use:

```
 d = {'parentkey1': {'value1': 3, 'value2': 0},
 'parentkey2': {'value1': 2, 'value2': 5},
 'parentkey3': {'value1': 6, 'value2': 9},
 'parentkey4': {'value1': 8, 'value2': 3}
 }

d = {k : dict(sorted(v.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])) for k, v in d.items()}
d
```

**output:**

```
{'parentkey1': {'value2': 0, 'value1': 3},
 'parentkey2': {'value1': 2, 'value2': 5},
 'parentkey3': {'value1': 6, 'value2': 9},
 'parentkey4': {'value2': 3, 'value1': 8}}
```

you can use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you want insertion order to be  guaranteed across other implementations of Python

Answer (score 1):

here you go.

```
  data = {'parentkey1': {'value1': 3, 'value2': 0},
  'parentkey2': {'value1': 2, 'value2': 5},
  'parentkey3': {'value1': 6, 'value2': 9},
  'parentkey4': {'value1': 8, 'value2': 3}
  }

  for key, value in data.items():
    print(value)

  print("\n")

  for key, value in data.items():
    new = {}
    if value["value1"] >=  value["value2"]:
      new["value2"] = value["value2"]
      new["value1"] = value["value1"]
    else:
      new["value1"] = value["value1"]
      new["value2"] = value["value2"]
    data[key] = new

  for key, value in data.items():
    print(value)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! Just one question, what if there is more than 2 values in the sub list of dictionaries?

Comment: kederrac's answer is the one you want. His makes me hate mine.

Answer (score 0):

Can do by simply switching values if value2 > value1 for each item

```
data = {'parentkey1': {'value1': 3, 'value2': 0},
  'parentkey2': {'value1': 2, 'value2': 5},
  'parentkey3': {'value1': 6, 'value2': 9},
  'parentkey4': {'value1': 8, 'value2': 3}
  }


for key, value in data.items():
    if value['value1'] > value['value2']:
        value['value1'], value['value2'] = value['value2'], value['value1']
```